# Java private method override

Tags: java, oop

I came across this scenario. We have a class lets say Main having a private method print. There is another class Main1 which extends Main class and redefines the print method. Since main1 is an object of Main1 class, I expect main1 print method to get called...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Main main1 = new Main1();
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       main1.print(list);
    }

    private void print(List<String> string) {
       System.out.println("main");
    }

}

class Main1 extends Main {
    public void print(List<String> string) {
       System.out.println("main1");
    }
}
```

In this case, when we run the program, it print "main". It really confuses me as that method is private and is not even part of Main1 class.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Why do you expect that it is not private, or part of Main1?

Comment: I'm confused too, how do you call `main1.print();` when there is no such method (`print` with no arguments)?

Comment: You already received the correct answer. This is the relevant [paragraph](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.8.1) from the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is not too hard:

- the *type* of the `main1` variable is `Main` (*not* `Main1`)
- so you can only call methods of that type
- the only possible method called `print` that accepts a `List<String>` on `Main` is the private one
- the calling code is inside the class `Main` so it can call a private method in that class

Therefore `Main.print(List<String>)` will be called.

Note that changing the type of `main1` to `Main1` will result in the *other* `print(List<String>)` method being called.

Comment: +1: If you make `print` non-private it will use inheritance. private members cannot follow inheritance.

Comment: I believe you missed the main point of the question, which is why Main.print() isn't overridden by Main1.print()

Comment: private method can not be overriden. That's language spec.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to override your `print` method you have to declare it `public`:

```
public class Main {

   public void print(List<String> string) {
   }

}
```

Otherwise it will call your private method without looking for the implementation in a derived class .

Answer (score 1):

Private method is not inherited and method overriding does not happened in your code.
You can see this by putting @Override annotation in Main1.print() method. If you put that annotation, compile error generated.

```
Main.java:17: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
1 error
```

In your case, Main1.print() and Main.print() are different and not related each other(no overriding, no overloading). So if you specify main1 as Main, Main.print() will be called. And if you specify main1 as Main1, Main1.print() will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Your main1 is a type of Main but instantiated with as Main1! It's OK since it is a subclass for Main. However, when you call the print method (BTW, it should be main1.print(list);) it will call the private method in the Main class! If you change the visibility of your method to protected or public, in this case print method in the Main1 class will be called because of polymorphic behavior of your instantiated object (remember, it is after all a Main1 object based on the code that you've provided!)